# How to do the proper SQLite query to a table with several foreign keys?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with two foreign keys pointing to the same table:

```
 CREATE TABLE person (
     id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     living_city INTEGER,
     birth_city INTEGER, 
     FOREIGN KEY (living_city) REFERENCES city(id),
     FOREIGN KEY (birth_city) REFERENCES city(id)
  )

 CREATE TABLE city (
     id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     name VARCHAR
 )
```

I have added some data so the tables looks like:

```
 person 
    1   peter   1   2
    2   mary    1   1
    3   ed      2   3

 city
    1   london
    2   paris
    3   rome
```

The question looks easy but I can find how to do it… I have already searched all google!!

I am looking for a query like the following but getting the foreign keys names, not the numbers(id):

> SELECT name, living_city, birth_city FROM person

The desired result is:

```
  > peter   london  paris
  > mary    london  london
  > ed      paris   rome
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the `person` table to the `city` table to achieve this.  It's fairly straight-forward SQL and suprising that 'all google' hasn't yielded a result for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, L.living_city, B.birth_city 
FROM person
INNER JOIN city as B
    ON birth_city = B.id
INNER JOIN  city as L
    ON living_city = L.id
```